# Cannot pass props in component from Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Hi I'm trying to pass props from my vue router but it's not printing anything and when logged in mounted it's returning undefined, but its giving value when I'm trying `console.log(this.$route.params.id);` when I try for `this.id` returns undefined or rather in my User template  its not outputting anything, same code is working in the online tutorial that I'm watching, please help me, is there any modification happened in a recent release

```js
let User = {
  props: ['id'],
  template: `
            <div>Hello # {{id}}</div>
        `,
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params); // this is returning the value
    console.log(this.id); // this is giving undefined
  }
}

let App = {
  template: `
            <div class="wrapper">
                <router-view></router-view>    
            </div>
        `
}

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/user/:id',
    component: User,
    props: true
  }, ],
})

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  components: {
    'app': App
  }
})

router.push('/user/1')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <app></app>
</div>
```

Comment: Your logs are not working. It is not mounted too.

Comment: That app looks incomplete, so there's not enough context to reproduce the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19 to run above example , in vscode install live server (ritwick dey) extension , and you can copy above code and creat index.html , in vs code right click on this index.html file , and open with live server , you will be able reproduce the issue

Comment: @DostonbekOripjonov the log will produce once you run above code on local server and go to the route path e.g http://localhost:8888/user/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using very old version of Vue Router. Just switch to current version - 3.5.2 - and your code will work as expected....

```js
let User = {
  props: ['id'],
  template: `
            <div>Hello # {{id}}</div>
        `,
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params); // this is returning the value
    console.log(this.id); // this is giving undefined
  }
}

let App = {
  template: `
            <div class="wrapper">
                <router-view></router-view>    
            </div>
        `
}

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/user/:id',
    component: User,
    props: true
  }, ],
})

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  components: {
    'app': App
  }
})

router.push('/user/1')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.5.2/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <app></app>
</div>
```